# ReflectionException in Container.php line 734: Class web does not exist (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am building a laravel blog application with laravel 5.2. and i am trying to add image upload functionality, as soon as i add package intervention/image with composer, I get the error below. when i remove the package the project starts to work fine again..i have tried older versions of the package but i still get the same issues...I think the content of one of my laravel files may be off because i downgraded from 5.4 to 5.2...but i don't know which. Please any help would be appreciated.

```
Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1
ReflectionException in Container.php line 734:
Class web does not exist
in Container.php line 734
at ReflectionClass->__construct('web') in Container.php line 734
at Container->build('web', array()) in Container.php line 629
at Container->make('web', array()) in Application.php line 697
at Application->make('web') in Pipeline.php line 126
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726..........
```

here is the content of my Kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

     /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    ];
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
        'auth:api',
    ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: May i please know why did you downgrade ? I'm working on laravel 5.6 with "intervention/image": "^2.4" and it's working smoothly, and i don't think above error is related to image uploading, there is no need of modifying Kernel class, either just follow the documentation carefully and you're good to go and always go with updated version of laravel.

Comment: @ViperTecPro Was following a tutorial, so i decided to go with the version that was being used in the tutorial. The error is not related to image uploading, but as soon as i require the package in composer, the application breaks and i get that error, otherwise it works fine.

Comment: Which intervention version are you using ? Can you show your composer,json here, clear cache : config,route,view and composer dump-autoload

Comment: There's a core difference between 5.2 and 5.4, and that's routes. In 5.2, they're in `app/Http/routes.php`, single file for api, web, etc. In 5.4 (maybe 5.3+) they were moved to `routes/{type}.php` (separate files for `api`, `web`, etc.). Also, there are some differences between `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` in each version, so double check the logic there. Lastly, try `composer dump-autoload`; that sometimes clears up `Reflection` Exceptions.

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks I'll try the suggestions now...

Comment: @ViperTecPro I'll show the composer.json

Comment: composer dump-autoload did fix it up, Thanks a lot guys...How do i mark an answer?